# Mysql in Erlang

Tags: mysql, server, erlang

I  want get data in Mysql by Erlang but the data output I get it show all col_name and it not render one by one

This is my output:

```
{selected,["id","first_name","last_name"],
                              [{1,"Matt","Williamson"},
                               {2,"Matt","Williamson2"},
                               {3,"Matt","Williamson3"}]}}
```

I'm using this code :

```
application:start(odbc),
ConnString = "DSN=mysqldb",
{ok, Conn} = odbc:connect(ConnString, []),
Results = odbc:sql_query(Conn, "SELECT * FROM test_table"),
io:format("~p",[Results]).
```

How can I don't get the {selected, [col_name]}?
And how to render data I get one by one like for loop in php using Erlang?

It render

```
{1,"Matt","Williamson"}{2,"Matt","Williamson2"}{3,"Matt","Williamson3"} have
```

I want it render like this

```
1 have Matt Williamson
2 have Matt Williamson2
3 have Matt Williamson3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty for help me I find a way to do that is use

```
{% for key,value1,value2 in username %}
```

in dtl file

Answer (score 2):

You may use pattern matching like this :

```
{selected, _Column, Data} = odbc:sql_query(Conn, "SELECT * FROM test_table"),
```

then use `io:format("~p",[Data]).`

and you will get :

```
[
 {1,"Matt","Williamson"},
 {2,"Matt","Williamson2"},
 {3,"Matt","Williamson3"}
]
```

Comment: I use this code to render it in HTML:

{ok, HTMLOutput} = hello_dtl:render([{username, Results}]),

But it show all data in one time.
Can you show me how to get Results it in a Variable render one by one ?

Comment: You may check the answer from Grant. He already provided the solution

Answer (score 2):

You just need a little more pattern-matching and the [lists:foreach](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foreach-2) function:

```erlang
{selected, _, Records} = odbc:sql_query(Conn, "SELECT * FROM test_table"),

lists:foreach(fun({Id, FName, LName}) ->
                  io:format("~p have ~s ~s~n", [Id, FName, LName])
              end, Records).
```

Output:

```
1 have Matt Williamson
2 have Matt Williamson2
3 have Matt Williamson3
```

Comment: how can I variable this list:foreach? 

I want to use hello_dtl:render([{username, Results}]) to render it to a variable in HTML